# Css for Blackberry only?

Tags: css, blackberry

I doubt this exists, but is there a way to make a css file only be read if it is a blackberry phone (lower then V6 is preferred, but if not that's ok)

I am using JQuery mobile so the css is perfect for everything else, I just wanna edit Blackberry

Comment: Maybe you could use a js script to check the User-Agent. In case it's a BlackBerry browser, you load your specific css

Comment: How could I do that? I (think) in C# its `if (Request.Headers["User-Agent"] != null &&  Request.Browser["BlackBerry"] == "true")`, but I'm not sure. What would it be in JS?

Comment: I think anirudh4444 answered that!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could check the browser name, in javascript, and make your css file as required. Conditional CSS for Backberry.

```
function getcss(cssfile){
loadcss = document.createElement('link')
loadcss.setAttribute("rel", "stylesheet")
loadcss.setAttribute("type", "text/css")
loadcss.setAttribute("href", cssfile)
document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(loadcss)
}
if(navigator.appName == 'option1')//or navigator.userAgent 
{
getcss('css/common_css_hd.css') 
}
else 
{
getcss('css/common_css.css')
}// JavaScript Document
```

Comment: How would I be able to tell if its black berry? Is there a way to tell that in JS?

Comment: navigator.appName is set to the browser name, "BlackBerry." See the code I posted, you will just have to modify the 'option1' text. Also see [this, under the navigator section](http://us.blackberry.com/devjournals/resources/journals/mar_2007/bdjs.jsp)

Comment: Im trying to install an emulator to run it now. My BB tester left

Comment: Okay.. read the documentation in the [link](http://us.blackberry.com/devjournals/resources/journals/mar_2007/bdjs.jsp) I left...

Comment: Ok. I have yet to be able to get a good emulator that I can run mobile web on through visual studio, but when I run the app through the 'Ripple' BB emulator in google chrome I get the "Netscape" as the `navigator.appName`. This may be because this is on a GC emulator though

Comment: Try this too *navigator.userAgent*

Comment: tried [this](http://www.softpedia.com/dyn-postdownload.php?p=140743&t=4&i=1) simulator?

Comment: navigator.userAgent worked correctly. I am installing the simulator now